# DevExpress MVC gridview page - same data shows up for different users

Tags: gridview, model-view-controller, devexpress

I have a DevExpress Gridview in a MVC project. The gridview shows data based upon the user that has logged in. If more than 1 user log in , the first user starts seeing the data that is specific to second user after the second user logs in.

For example:

1. User1 logs in and sees the data *[Apple, Banana, Mango]* in grid based upon his role and permission.
2. User2 logs in and sees the data *[Pineapple, Strawberries]* in the grid based upon his role and permission.
3. If User1 refreshes his grid by selecting a different page size , User1 starts seeing *[Pineapple, Strawberries]* now.

It seems that some datamodel or other local session information is making to the application cache or to the server. Can you please help identifying what setting I should use to prevent this?

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
    userName = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    return View(new MyTransactionsModel { 
                    MasterData = GridViewTransactionsModel.GetUserMasterDataTable(userName), 
                    ChangesetData = new DataTable(), 
                    ChangesetNumbers = GridViewTransactionsModel.GetChangesetNumbers(userName), 
                    ChangesetNo = 0, 
                    ChangesetName = null, 
                    ChangesetStatus = null, 
                    ChangesetComments = null
               });

}
```

Appreciate your help

Rajnish

Comment: It looks like when the second user logs in the the Authentication Cookies and session of User1 are now replaced with that of User2. So whatever data you are retrieving about the currently logged in user, it comes for the user2 only. Mostly authentication mechanism write Auth Cookie in the browser and that cookie name is static. So when user2 logs in the cookie created for the User1 gets overwritten. Can you share how are you deciding if user is logged in or not?

Comment: Seems like it. I am new to .Net and MVC world. How do I disable these cookies and session going to the server? I forgot to mention the users are logging from different machines. I am getting the username from Session, which is set upon user login. Using the Session to bring the relevent data and pass to View in Index Controller. Attaching the code in the question for reference.

Comment: If user's are logging in from different machines than this should not happen at all. I was assuming that the users using the same machine. Anyway this is tricky.I If users are using different machines/browsers then there should not be conflict between their sessions. Would you mind sharing the way you are authenticating the user and setting up the session? Using session in MVC is not recommended though.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Using a custom login page, and set Session["UserName"] after successful login. Then in the Index action of page where I am having issue, I run a query based upon UserName pulled from Session.